# Definir sombra na tabela HTML e-mail

Tags: html

Estou enviando HTML e-mail com PHP e defini uma tabela com sombra, estilizei com `box-shadow`, mas não funcionou... Alguma ajuda para definir sombra no HTML email usando uma tabela?

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML e CSS que tens?

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar este código **CSS**:

```
table { box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; }
```

Para mais informações pode consultar o seguinte [site](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) ou [este](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_shadows.asp).

Se após tentar isto não resultar, edite a pergunta e junte o código que está a usar para que o possa ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Com esse código você compatibilidade em **TODOS** os navegadores.

```css
table {
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Sobrenome</th>
      <th>Idade</th>
    <tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Leonardo</td>
      <td>Bonetti</td>
      <td>19</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Já tinha shadow usando -moz-boz-shadow, -weblit-box-shadow e boz-shadow, porém quando envio o html e-mail para o gmail simplesmente não aparece a sombra, instalei um outro leito de e-mail no meu celular, enviei e-mail e aparece a sombra. Pesquisando achei o link abaixo que mostra que o gmail não suporta shadow. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @RRV Nossa o email passou por mim e eu nem percebi ao ler o email, realmente o gmail não aceita shadow, aliás o gmail nao aceita muitas coisas.

Answer (score 0):

Muitos clientes de email (ex. Gmail) ignoram códigos CSS mais arrojados, bem como ignoram importação de código CSS externos (.css) ou inseridos numa `<head>`.

Use o CSS *inline* nos elementos com *style*. Ex:

```
<elemento style="..."></elemento>
```

E não use códigos, como disse, mais arrojados (`box-shadow` seria um deles). Use estilos mais básicos como, `background`, `color`, `border` etc... Estes são renderizados normalmente.

Outra regra geral é fazer o HTML o mais simples possível, usando TABLEs em vez de DIVs.